# Angular2 directive based on dynamically added css class

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-directives

Angular router's `[routerLink]` directive adds CSS class `router-link-active` to active link. I'd like to write directive based on this class.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({selector: '.router-link-active'})
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el:ElementRef) {
        el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
}
```

However it doesn't work as I expect.

It works if directive is hard coded in template:

```
<a class="router-link-active">Feature1</a>
```

but it doesn't work when css class is added dynamically by `routerLink`:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/feature1']">Feature1</a>
```

Although CSS class is added, directive code is not fired.

These are my very first steps with Angular2, so maybe the solution is easy, but I cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's not supported. Angular2 instantiates components and directives only to selectors that match HTML statically added to a components template. Anything dynamic is ignored (HTML added using `[innerHTML]="..."` or attributes or classes added dynamically.